# How to define a String by build types in Gradle (Android Studio) and replace the file name

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to replace the name of the generated apks by the specified build type:

```
android {
   buildTypes {
      def String proguard

      release {
         minifyEnabled false
         zipAlignEnabled true
         proguard = "noproguard"
      }

      releaseProguard {
         minifyEnabled true
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

         zipAlignEnabled true
         proguard = "proguard"
      }

   }

   // Replace the file names
   android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.preBuild.doLast {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(
                        output.outputFile.parent,
                        output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}-${variant.versionCode}-" + proguard +.apk"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I make a signed APK with "release", I'm not getting the "noproguard" string in the APK's file name, it's getting overriden by the last build type: releaseProguard.

Expected output **release**:
app-qa-release-1.3.1-noprguard.apk

Expected output **releaseProguard**: app-qa-release-1.3.1-proguard.apk

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly what you are looking for.

You can use your `build.gradle` to set this attribute:

```
android {
    //...

    defaultConfig {
        //...
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "XXXX_" + defaultConfig.versionCode);
    }
}
```

Assigning the `archivesBaseName` you will obtain something like:

```
xxxx_0.9.6-flavorName-buildType.apk
```

You can use this inside the flavor block to assign specific value.

This attribute requires the gradle-plugin `1.3.1` or higher.

Comment: Do you mean that one can assign any arbitrary string value to versionCode and it will be reflected in the apk name?

Comment: @RaGe No. You can assign a arbitrary value to the archivesBaseName that will be a prefix in the name before "-flavorName-buildType.apk". Of course you can write tasks to rename the final apk, but it is a built-in feature in the gradle-plugin for android.